# What is the Life time of Static methods inside a non static class

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have a below factory UI class which is responsible for creating controls for my views. I want to know what would be the life time of these controls that is getting created from the Static CreateUI Method .

```
public class UIFactory
{
  public static Control CreateUI (string ControlType)
   { 
     if ControlType == "Date"
      return new dateControl();
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The static methods' life time equals to the life time of the class (of the type). The life time of the objects returned from those methods depends on how you use those objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods don't have a lifetime. They are there. Always.

*(There probably is a more sophisticated explanation about lazy loading assemblies and just-in-time-compilation, but for the garbage collector, they don't matter. Methods **exist**. They don't have a lifetime. They never get removed.)*

Instances all have the same lifetime: until the last reference to them goes out of scope and the garbage collector comes along to remove them.

It does not matter who created an instance. It only matter who holds a reference to it. Your method does not keep a reference to the created instance, so the caller will decide about the lifetime (by being the only one with a reference to it, until the caller gives access to somebody else).

Comment: Not actually... You can unload an `AppDomain`, and then some methods don't exist anymore.

Comment: @dymanoid While true, that means that *everything* in that app domain is gone and it's either the end of the process, or somebody did it manually, on purpose. There is no sneaky garbage collector going around finding methods that weren't called in a while and removing them.

Comment: I thought we're talking about life time in general and not about garbage collecting specifically. If an `AppDomain` is unloaded, then any call in that domain will cause an `AppDomainUnloadedException`.

Comment: I might quibble over "last reference" versus something like "reachable". After all, the GC notably can clean up object graphs containing cycles.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Indeed, my answer is a broad simplification of what happens, but I think explaining all the details would be too much here.

Comment: @nvoigt Sorry for the confusion, not the life time of static method.What i meant was the life time of the objects that is getting created inside the static method.

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime of objects created this way will be exactly the same as the one of objects created by a non-static method. Simple as that.